# What does "commit your changes or stash them" mean?

Tags: git, version-control

I have my branch on my GIT repository where I used to commit and push. But today I saw a different programmer committed and pushed to my branch. Now when I try to pull the latest branch  GIT completes it half way and then gives error "Either commit your changes or stash them". I have no idea what that means and I don't want to commit before taking his latest changes on my branch. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that you have uncommitted changes, which prevents you from pulling.

And you solve it by either committing them or [stashing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) them. Just like the error message says.

(By the way, you typically get better answers by asking precise questions. If you want to know what `git stash` is, ask *that*. Simply asking "how do I solve the problem where Git tells me to commit or stash" simply leads to answers like "you should commit or stash".

Git itself has already answered your question. If you didn't understand *that* answer, ask about the part you don't understand.

Comment: I'll try to add more background to this answer for Tim Tom. Pulling means fetching remote changes *and* merging them. Merging can only happen with the help of the work tree -- this is because there's no other sensible way to handle possible conflicts: you have to be able to actually edit the files with conflicts. Consequently, if you have uncommitted changes and tell Git to merge something, it sees the dirty work tree and ask you to make the work tree clean: either by committing these changes or temporarily removing them using the stash.